# Hit Ajax only when user will add row in sql PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, codeigniter

We dont want to hit ajax again and again that slow down the POS other process

so now we want ajax only hit when user enter some data from front end site 
like we have a cart in POS and hitting ajax again and again slow down the POS other process

we want that if user add the food item from front end of site then it will show in POS in backend of POS at same time by hitting the ajax

but how can i know the item is added 
this can be done by hitting the ajax again and again but i dont want that 
i want the ajax hit only when got some new result in SQL Database.

time interval of jquery is not good answer

any other idea ?

Comment: Can you show some code, why don't you add onclick listener on your add to cart button and then send ajax request to your backend ? Or you can wait till the user click procceed to check out and send list of all items in the cart ? Would need to see some code to help you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to use web sockets for real time updations. Check this out http://socketo.me/ (or) https://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

Well i think your answer for that is javascript(jquery library probably to make your life easier) and let me explain why.

First of all ajax is the "chain" that connects front-end to back-end. As you know php can not "see" the DOM and the only way is to use `forms` , give names to elements that will be called in the back-end etc etc and inside the form call the php class you need. The downside of this, is that once clicked the page refreshes.

On the other hand we have javascript which is based on the front-end interactions. Javascript can take care of all the changes in front-end and handle things there (like element on focus,on click etc etc). A personal point of view is that javascript is the "eyes" of php in front-end side (of course it's even more just trying to simplify).

So now that we said that let's talk about your problem. From what i understood your code works you are just talking about optimization. The only way to know if the user has added anything in the food-field you are mentioning is if you can "see" the field (javascript).

I understand that you don't want to trigger ajax, that calls php class that queries the db. That means that you have to put conditions in front-end side or even in the back end.

From *front-end* side you can check your field when user clicks out of it (focus_lost):

```
$( "#food_field" ).blur(function() {
  //ajax call
});
```

Or another solution whould be to add a `button` something like "Submit" and set your jquery to trigger ajax on click like:

```
$( "#Submit" ).click(function() {
  //ajax call
});
```

On the back-end you could just use if condition. What i mean is you can keep trigger your ajax but you don't have to query the db. For example if the data that the user sends is empty you can just do something like this:

```
if($food_field<>''){
//query the db
}
```

That way you will only query the db when you get a value in the field that you are interested.

You can even count the letters of your data that is send like :

```
    if(strlen($food)>6){
    //query the db
    }
```

Conclusion is that there are solutions in the back-end and front-end. My personal humble opinion is that if you want to take care of things in the front-end you "filter" them in the front-end as you can manage them easier there.

Comment: appreciate your answer
but let suppose their are two side of the WEB APP
one is front end where you can order the food item and add them to cart and second is POS which is backend 
now suppose you are on other place and i am in food court then 
when you add the product in your basket with specify the table no at the same time i will open that  table no in POS
Now Same table is open in front of me 
now you order add some food item in cart then when you add the item it goes in cart table
but for get those food item i have to hit a ajax which will get result from sql 
i dont want that hit

Comment: i want like when ever use will add the item at that same time one request will hit from my side and get the result from sql 
rest of things to show is my responsibilities